# getting error of ora 00979 not a group by expression in lumen with oracle

Tags: php, oracle, group-by, lumen

> I am using lumen with oracle database and getting error on query with
> group by.not undestand the problem because its working with mysql.

```
"ora 00979 not a group by expression"
```

my query :

```
DB::table('company')
->select('company.name','branch.id','branch.name','branch.id','branch.branch_com_id')
->leftjoin('branch', 'company.id', '=', 'branch_com_id')
->groupBy('branch.branch_com_id')
->get()
->toArray();
```

**I am trying to groupby rows from branch table with branch_com_id but its showing above error.
i tried with adding `strict mode => false` in .env and database.php but still its not working for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, what Oracle gets is a query like

```
select company.name, branch.id, branch.name, branch.id, branch.branch_com_id
from ...
group By branch.branch_com_id
```

which clearly gives the issue.

If you need to extract `company.name, branch.id, branch.name, branch.id`, you need to use them in the `group by` clause; differently, you may need to use aggregation functions (like `sum`, `min`, ..) over this columns, but this depends on the logic you need